# How to override generic isEqualTo from AbstractAssert

Tags: assertj

The method with a generic parameter in its interface:

```java
interface Assert<S, A> {
    S isEqualTo(A expected);
```

is overridden with `Object` parameter in its abstract class:

```java
abstract class AbstractAssert<S ..., A> implements Assert<S, A> {
    @Override
    S isEqualTo(Object expected)
```

How to override `isEqualTo()` with the generic parameter `A` of `Assert<S, A>`, as

```java
class MyAssert extends AbstractAssert<MyAssert, MyClass> {
    @Override
    MyAssert isEqualTo(MyClass expected)
```

fails because of type erasure:

> name clash: isEqualTo(MyClass) in MyAssert overrides a method whose erasure is the same as another method, yet neither overrides the other
>
> first method:  isEqualTo(Object) in AbstractAssert
>   second method: isEqualTo(A#2) in Assert
>   where A#1,A#2 are type-variables:
>   A#1 extends Object declared in class AbstractAssert
>   A#2 extends Object declared in interface Assert

Is there another way?

What `assertJ` gain of shadowing the generic parameter with Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `isEqualTo` to take an `Object` as parameter is to be flexible.

Example:

```
Object name = "John";
// would not compile if isEqualTo expected a String parameter 
assertThat("John").isEqualTo(name);
```

You can't override a method and narrow its parameters type.